# how to deploy NextJS 13 to AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, next.js13

is it possible to deploy nextjs app to aws lambda? if possible how to do it?

I want to deploy and run my NextJS application in SSR mode on aws Lambda

Answer (score 0):

you can check https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-nextjs.

but nextjs uses memory caches on the instance(https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#configuring-caching).

originally, it also uses a file cache, but that doesn't work with lambdas because file writes are only allowed to specific directories.

so multiple lambdas can cause problems. So I decided to use redis(https://caching-tools.github.io/next-shared-cache/redis).

And there can be also cold start issues.